# Non committed files that show up in github

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I have been using GitHub desktop as I currently have a Windows OS, and for some reason files that I do not commit are being pushed to the repo. I have double-checked all my commits and the files are not there, but when I look at the actual repository on GitHub, the files are there, even when I have purposely deleted them. I can't find any information on this happening, does anyone know if this is common

Comment: What type of files? What commands are you using when adding and pushing to the repo?

Comment: @Jeff Gruenbaum Temporary latex files (.aux, .log, etc.) I'm using GitHub desktop gui so I select the different files to commit, commit them, and push. I haven't been using the command prompt because I'm working on windows

Answer (score 0):

Try and clone your repository again, in a new local folder, with GitHub Desktop.

If you see those temporary files in your local clone:

- delete them
- make sure your .gitignore ignores them
- go back to GitHub Desktop, add and commit to record the deletion
- push